# Excel unique values multiple rows

Tags: excel

I have 100 animals each of which have been dissected. Each animal eats a different type of prey. So I have list

```
Animal 1. eats prey type 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
Animal 2. eats prey type 1,6, 7
Animal 3. eats prey type 1,2
```

I know how to calculate the number of unique prey items for each animal, but unsure as to formulae to calculate the cumulative number of unique prey items as we move from animal 1 to 3 i.e unique number of prey for animal 1 is 6, animal 2 is 1 (7 is new prey), animal 3 is 0 (as no new prey types).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It sometimes helps to write out calculated values in their own cells.  If you had a column indicating how many unique prey is eaten by an animal, then the cumulative sum is each animal's calculated value added together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a formula answer:

[image]

In I2 the following array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$G1,$B2:$G2)=0,IF($B2:$G2<>"",1,0)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter or Tab when exiting edit mode.  Then drag down.

Comment: Awesome response. Works great. Really appreciate the help

Comment: @Matt Glad it helped.  Please mark as correct by clicking on the green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.  It will close the question as being answered.

Comment: Thanks again Scott, I can't find any green check mark to tick by the answer? is it on this page, or do I go somewhere else?

Comment: @Matt is located directly below the big number zero in the upper left corner of this answer.

Comment: O.K. Great have clicked. On my screen it was a light grey color and looked like a chevron below the zero so hard to see. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

a: the general list of type of prey , b: is the new list to compare with a :

```
Function Newvalues(a As Range, b As Range)
Dim k = b.Count
For i = 1 To a.Count
For j = 1 To b.Count
If a(i) = b(j) And a(i) <> "" And b(j) <> "" Then
k = k - 1
End If
Next j
Next i
Newvalues = k
End Function
```

k is the number of new values

Comment: Awesome response. Works great. Really appreciate the help